# Relative strengths/weaknesses of Fair Folk and Demons

Tags: exalted

On a general rule, what are the relative strengths and weaknesses of Wyld creatures (mutants, Fair Folk) versus Malfeas creatures (demons, Infernals) in a combat situation?

Does this change whether the fight happens in Creation, in the Wyld, or in Malfeas?

Note that I am strictly asking about straight mechanical advantages - not "there are more of X than Y" or "X has better infrastructure than Y", but more "X is immune to Y's charms" or "X's charms are more effective against Y".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the errata a lot has changed for the Fair folk. They are undenyable more potent once you go into the wyld and the deeper you venture the more potent they become.

Unless they learn special charms the Fair folk cannot exist safely in the underworld. Though Malfeas poses less of a problem.

Fair folk scale in power comparable to demons, Infernal Exalted should be able to quickly learn how to mop the floor with them provided they lear a few tricks to help them defend against shaping attacks.